# Outgoing Email body + attachments limit

Tags: email

I recently got told that the limit for outgoing email was raised to 10MB for body + attachments. So I thought, let me try that!

Source based on: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en_US

After seeing the row with "Email Services: Maximum Size of Email Message (Body and Attachments)" said 10MB, I then decided to give this a go on 2 sandboxes.
The first sandbox is Winter'15 and the other sandbox is Spring'15.

So my attachment has a size of 4MB and the body was just a single word.
Now when I received the mail ( from both sandboxes ), the attachment got converted to .html.

Can someone confirm that the total size of the outgoing email hasn't been raised, but still is 3MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf), the maximum size of a single email attachment for Email to Salesforce is 5MB and the maximum size of total attachments is 10MB. The email body gets truncated at 32kb.

For Email Services, the maximum size of Email (body and attachments) is 10MB.

Email-to-Case, On-Demand-Email-to-Case and Mail Merges have different limits. See the above reference for details.